# Were the Knights of Ren originally part of the dark or light side?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I'm getting my sources seriously messed up here so bear with me. I'm sort of getting the message here that they were originally trained by Luke and later corrupted or wiped out but the other half of people are saying that they were formed by Snoke as soon as Ben turned to the dark side.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could provide examples of conflicting sources then that would help people to better frame their answer.

Comment: I thought all we knew about the Knights of Ren so far was one fairly oblique mention by Snape/Snope/whatever his name was in *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite When has lack of information ever stopped anybody from claiming things as fact?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: all the time, here! We’re guarding the flame of fact with the firey wrath of our downvotes.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Unfortunately the rest of the Internet doesn't have our high standards for evidence. Not to mention all those people expressing opinions *off* the Internet...

Comment: What's an "off the Internet"?

Comment: @Nate - it's some new-fangled kind of platform where people actually speak to each other in person. Like, with their voices. I'm sure it's just a fad - something like that won't last.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The group of Force sensitives that Luke was training were not the Knights of Ren. They were intended to become a new generation of Jedi.

We don't know anything at all about the Knights of Ren, other than the fact that Kylo is one of them and was called "Master of the Knights of Ren" by Snoke. They seemed to be a group of Dark Side Force users, but otherwise, we don't know where they came from, how Kylo found them, or if Snoke is a part of that group or not.

Comment: Do we know for certain that the Knights of Ren aren't what the survivors/mutineers in Luke's class *became*, after Ben/Kylo revolted?

Comment: we don't know *anything*, really, though Han's explanation that Kylo "destroyed" them strongly implies that they mostly didn't survive.

Comment: Do you know what that exact line was? Since it's virtually the only thing we have to go on, the quote would be a good addition to this answer `:-)` I don't remember the exact wording, just that I interpreted it at the time as meaning "ruined what Luke tried to create" while others interpreted it as "killed all the others"

Comment: @user568458 - There's a transcript [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=star-wars-episode-vii-the-force-awakens)--it says that Luke "was training a new generation of Jedi. One boy, an apprentice, turned against him, destroyed it all." And at another point Snoke says to Kylo Ren, "Even you, master of the Knights of Ren, have never faced such a test." (that's the only mention of the 'Knights of Ren' in the movie, assuming the transcript is accurate).

Comment: Obviously the Knights of Ren are an offshoot of The Knights of Ni.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield although there is some precedence for the use of "killed" to mean "turn to the dark side" e.g., Darth Vader "killed" Anakin

Comment: @omegacron - You mean meatspace?  Gross.  That's that place that has that giant ball of fire.  Terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

What we know:
Knights of Ren are NOT Sith. They don't follow the rule of two created by Darth Bane.

We know, some canon, some not, that there are many Force users besides Siths and Jedis.

There's Dark Jedis, Witches of Dathomir, Sith pure race, etc.

We know that, or they are to naive, or they're not so greedy as the Sith so they don't need the role ot two. Maybe they even WERE HIDEN from the Sith!!!

My theory, sorry to not append some material here, but everything is so fresh and new, my theory is that **knights of Ren were CREATED BY VADER!!!**

We know from canon that Darth Vader wanted to kill Darth Sidius, and called Luke to enjoy it. (Episode VI).

Maybe Vader trained in secret Snoke willing to kill Sidius and set up his own empire.

This would add A LOT to Kylo Ren's motivation!!! Knowing that here's in a institution created by his grand father.

As we know from Episode VII, Kylo fears he will not be as great as Vader, and we know that he wants to resume what Vader started. A new order...