# Is there evidence to suggest Kylo Ren went to the dark side so he could help the light side?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, kylo-ren

We know that Kylo Ren is associated with the [Knights of Ren](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111884/were-the-knights-of-ren-originally-part-of-the-dark-or-light-side), who are a different group to the Jedi from Luke’s academy.

In the movie Kylo Ren seems conflicted, and he even asks his father for help.

Now you can argue this scene works on [two levels](http://brobible.com/entertainment/article/star-wars-the-force-awakens-fan-theory/).

1. It potentially proves that Kylo Ren is going to the dark side, and so Kylo deceives and abuses his father’s trust.
2. Another interpretation is that Kylo needs to create the appearance of going to the Dark side, and so his father helps him in the long run.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest Kylo Ren went to the dark side so he could help the light side?**

Comment: What spoilers? If you've not seen the film, it means nothing. If you have, well, it's not going to spoil it.

Comment: Not much point in editing the title when the character's name is one of the tags.

Comment: Everyone: please avoid "this character" in titles, as long as it's not a huge spoiler. In this case, it's not: everyone knows there is a menacing Dark Side character, named Kylo Ren, in this movie. Of those who don't, it's likely because they aren't interested in the movie. Conclusion: not a spoiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DISCLAIMER:

The question **did not ask if** the theory was correct. It asked if there was **any evidence supporting** it (vs. refuting it).

Despite the evidence listed below, I don't think the theory is correct, for a variety of reasons that contradict it, including Occam's razor as well as word of god (JJ Abrams).

---

I don't know of any canon in-universe evidence to support that theory with any degree of certainty.

However, breaching the Fourth Wall, there is some evidence to support the theory:

A LOT LOT LOT of the new Disney canon seems to be - deliberately or not - mirroring Original Trilogy, in great detail.

He tells Vader's helmet "`I will finish what you started`".

So, what exactly DID Vader start?

- Start as emo unbalanced teenager. Check
- Betray your Jedi friends and teachers. Check
- Murder other Jedi students and all Jedi. Check
- Join the Dark Side (Sith in his case) as main apprentice to main Dark Sider. Check
- Bicker with the Dark Lord's highest military figure over the Force vs. Military Force. Check.
- Kidnap a powerful female Force User (preferably, of Skywalker Bloodline, your relative). Check (relative part is likely but uncertain).
- Try to get location of important Rebel info from kidnaped powerful female Force User, only to lose her when she's busted out by Han Solo brandishig blasters from Millenium Falcon? Check, mostly.
- Murder a bunch of innocent people so your Dark/Sith master thinks you're on his side. Check.
- Betray and murder your father? (according to Obi-Wan Kenobi). Check
- Bring balance to the Force, **by betraying and murdering your Dark/Sith master**: ***Episodes VIII or rather IX?***

Comment: Not according to this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111374/51226

Comment: @RogueJedi - I didn't say that it was a **correct conclusion**. Obviously it isn't, that's a fan theory that makes little sense. However, the question **did not ask if the theory was correct**. It asked **if there was any evidence *supporting* it**

Comment: Could you point me to something that explains what you mean by 'fourth wall' - I understood it to be a performance thing where you hide what goes on backstage.

Comment: @hawkeye - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall . I used it in a sense of "let's bring in the things about the films themselves, into the content of the films". Sort of like a comic character talking to the comic artist

Comment: what is the link for what JJ Abrams said about this?

Comment: @hawkeye  - I'm 99% sure the quote is in one of the linked questions.

Comment: Are you talking about this one?
“Kylo Ren idolizes Darth Vader, not Anakin Skywalker,” Abrams explained. “He idolizes what Vader represents..."

Comment: @hawkeye = yes, that's one of them

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no evidence to suggest this. As you said, some things are open to interpretation, but nothing concretely supports your theory. There are also multiple points working against your theory.

> First, you seem to be forgetting that Kylo Ren murdered the other Jedi students and, at least temporarily, prohibited the return of the Jedi Order.

If he secretly wanted to help the light side, he sure as heck didn't do it 
well.

Additionally, he talks to Vader's helmet about continuing his mission when no one else is around. We know from [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111374/51226) that the mission he wants to continue is negative. He would have absolutely no reason to do this if he was secretly a light-sider.

Comment: In all fairness... he COULD have talked to Vader's helmet about continuing his mission to Bring Balance to the Force by wiping out Sith.... you know, like Vader did, by joining, them, murdering a bunch of people, then betraying and killing his SIth master.

Comment: Wasn't Vader's actual mission about bringing 'balance' to the force?

Comment: @DVK Not according to this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111374/51226

Comment: @RogueJedi - tell that to Khan, who most certainly was NOT in ST2 reboot according to J.J. Abrams ;)